# How to log API Errors on my server?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In my Facebook App Insights I see a section called "API Errors Returned" which indicate that I have a few API Errors everyday.

How can I log all the API Errors my App generates so I can fix them or at least know what's wrong?

Comment: See the result of each API request call

Comment: Everything is fine. My App is used by about 1250-2000 users daily and I see 2 - 20 API Errors in my App insights. I want to know why these API Errors acquire.

Comment: so log them on your side. If there are 2 api errors happened - then you could log them, but you didn't.

Comment: zerkms, this is my the subject of my question! :)

Comment: How can I log them on my server (my side as you called it)?

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting API errors returned according to Insights.  But the Most Common Errors list is empty.  Is this a bug?

I believe these API errors are related to a bug we have uncovered and has yet to be fixed by Facebook.  The bug we have open with them has had it's status changed and we cannot get them to re-open it.  Our website app (FilmCrave.com) is behaving like it has a canvas URL when we do not have one set.  In our Basic App settings page, we only have Website checked, App on Facebook is NOT checked (this is where you set your canvas URL).

Thanks,
Nick
FilmCrave.com